# TikZ angle arithmetic

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm running into a problem when trying to draw vector components in a TikZ picture. I want to be able to have TikZ do the following:
1) Draw a line of length 4 at 0 degrees
2) Draw a line from (4,0) of length 3 at 90 degrees
3) Draw the hypotenuse from (4,3) of length 5 at 210 degrees

However, when using coordinate arithmetic and angles in TikZ, I can't get the hypotenuse right. Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) coordinate (a);
    \draw (a) -- ($(a)+(0:4)$) coordinate (b);
    \draw (b) -- ($(b)+(90:3)$) coordinate (c);
    \draw (c) -- ($(c)+(210:5)$);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: broken triangle]

I've been trying to find a solution and run out of ideas. Any help (including the pointing out of boneheaded mistakes) would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,
JLusk

Comment: The final angle is not 210.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the final angle is not 210; either use the appropriate value `atan(3/4)+180` or use `cycle` (or `(a)` since you already named the initial coordinate); notice also that you can use just one `\draw` and the the use of `++` simplifies your code (no need for the `calc` library):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) coordinate (a) -- 
    ++(0:4) coordinate (b) --
    ++(90:3) coordinate (c) --
    ++({atan(3/4)+180}:5);
\end{tikzpicture}\bigskip

\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) coordinate (a) -- 
    ++(0:4) coordinate (b) --
    ++(90:3) coordinate (c) --
    cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you insist on four separate operations, you can do

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
    \draw (a) -- +(0:4) coordinate (b);
    \draw (b) -- +(90:3) coordinate (c);
    \draw (c) -- +({atan(3/4)+180}:5);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

or simply

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
    \draw (a) -- +(0:4) coordinate (b);
    \draw (b) -- +(90:3) coordinate (c);
    \draw (c) -- (a);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

both options still without `calc`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! In my head, a 3:4:5 triangle was a 30-60-90 triangle. There is no rational reason why I thought this, but there you go.